# react-router not changing pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

No matter which route I access, react-router (v4) is returning the home page, but when I route by parsing the urls and render with a switch statement, it works fine.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => <div>home page</div>
const About = () => <div>about page</div>

render((
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

I'm using Apache server and a Laravel/PHP backend, so the urls look like `localhost/calendar/public` and `localhost/calendar/public/about`, which might be the problem. However, whenever I use another route (e.g. `localhost/calendar/public/foo`) the server returns that the page does not exist.

**EDIT**

Here's a way I got it working, but it's more of a hack than a solution and I'm still not sure why the original problem arose.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const url  = new URL(window.location.href)
const isDev = (url.host == "localhost")

const browserApp = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${isDev ? "/calendar/public/" : "/"}`} component={Home}/>
      <Route path={`${isDev ? "/calendar/public/about" : "/about"}`} component={About}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) object to the [`<Router ... />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) component or use one of the high-level routers e.g. [`<BrowserRouter />`](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/BrowserRouter). See docs:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: I'm actually using BrowserRouter (just added import statement to my question to make that clear).

Answer (score -2):

Your conts are no Compponents. You need to make real components a minimal example of a component could be

import React, {Component} from "react";

```
class Foo extends Component {

       constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {        
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div/>)}
   }
```

then you can Import it in your routing

```
import Foo from "PATH";
```

then you can use it in routing

And also it would be better to use this:

```
 <Router history={createHistory}>
```

an additional problem could be your htaccess. Are there errors in console?

Comment: They are stateless functional components.

Comment: what are steless functional components? the ones above?